# Invariant Violation - Conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

This is driving me insane and I can't spot the issue. I'm trying to conditionally render an image component but it's throwing `Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component`. Not even using a text string where the statement is.

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={newsItemStyles.wrapper}>
            {this.state.isLoading && (
                <View style={loadingOverlayStyles.container}>
                    <ActivityIndicator />
                    <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
                </View>
            )}
            {this.props.item.uri && ( // this is there the error is thrown
                <View>
                    <Image
                        style={{width: '100%', height: 250}}
                        source={{uri: this.props.item.uri}}
                    />
                </View>
            )}
            <TouchableHighlight
              onPress={() =>
                this.props.navigation.navigate('NewsSingle', {
                  item: this.props.item,
                  title: this.props.item.title,
                  favorite: this.props.favorite,
                })
              }>
              <Text numberOfLines={2}>{this.props.item.title}</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            {this.props.favorite ? (
                <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={this.unfavorite}>
                    <FontAwesome5 name="bookmark" size={18} solid />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            ) : (
                <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={this.favorite}>
                    <FontAwesome5 name="bookmark" size={18} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli how does this help with the error above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is simple. You have to be careful when rendering components like:

```
someCondition && <someComponent />
```

Because there are some values that JSX will render as a text. An example of this, `0`, this is a falsy value that JSX won't render as a boolean.

To fix this you just have to use the double negation operator to get the appropriate boolean value just like:

```
            {!!this.props.item.uri && ( // error won't throw
                <View>
                    <Image
                        style={{width: '100%', height: 250}}
                        source={{uri: this.props.item.uri}}
                    />
                </View>
            )}
```

Comment: Now that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Ill modularize the code and issue should be solved otherwise letme know:

```
returnImage = () => (<View>
                        <Image
                            style={{width: '100%', height: 250}}
                            source={{uri: this.props.item.uri}}
                        />
                    </View>)


displayImage = () => {
let renderData = this.props.item.uri ? this.returnImage():null


}

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={newsItemStyles.wrapper}>
                {this.state.isLoading && (
                    <View style={loadingOverlayStyles.container}>
                        <ActivityIndicator />
                        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
                    </View>
                )}
                {}
                <TouchableHighlight
                  onPress={() =>
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('NewsSingle', {
                      item: this.props.item,
                      title: this.props.item.title,
                      favorite: this.props.favorite,
                    })
                  }>
                  <Text numberOfLines={2}>{this.props.item.title}</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
                {this.props.favorite ? (
                    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={this.unfavorite}>
                        <FontAwesome5 name="bookmark" size={18} solid />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                ) : (
                    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={this.favorite}>
                        <FontAwesome5 name="bookmark" size={18} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                )}
            </View>
        );
    }
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. Creating a function to return the component is a work around. But I would ideally like to know if there is anything wrong with my code or an issue with RN.

Comment: the issue will be of that you may have extra white spaces just after view and before image, thats the most common error, and in large scale application you should modularize your code, not like the one you have written.